# how remove password2 field from django createsuperuser?

Tags: django

I am working on a project and want to find a way to remove password2 field in createsuperuser. I used BaseAbstractUser class and changed username to Email field but after searxhes alot couldn't found any way to:
when I run python manage.py Createsuperuser it asks Email and after that password. after entering password I don't want re-enter password.

I checked this way but couldn't found useful

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should customize `createsuperuser` management command and modify this piece of code ( [here in django github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9fd3a0ffc8fb8e532b0d5717f99fb15aff175a6c/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py#L171) )

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I'm noob in Django and I don't know how to do that. Can you give me an example please? I created customuser by: https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/